# Microsoft Remote Desktop getting native res on scaled Mac

Tags: macos, windows, remote-desktop

I have a feeling there is no solution for this but ....

1. My Mac is connected to a 38" wide monitor, native res 3840x1600
2. My Mac is running in scaled mode, effective res (3200x1333)
3. I connect to my PC via remote desktop.

   **Result:** It makes a 3200x1300 display (because that's the res Mac tells apps it is). That resolution is then scaled to 3840x1600. This both (a) looks bad because of the scaling and (b) looks giant, sizes are too large (or display res is too small depending on your POV)
4. I set Microsoft Remote Desktop -> Display to 3840x1600

   **Result:** It get a 3200x1333 window of a 3840x1600 display that I have to scroll around to see
5. I tried checking "Optimize for Retina Displays"

   **Result:** It gave me a Windows desktop that is 6400x2666 which still basically has both problems as the first result (a) it looks bad because of scaling and (b) everything is too small

What I want to happen is I want Windows to have a 3840x1600 display and have Remote Desktop display that fullscreen so there is no scaling from windows to Mac even though Mac is running in this scaled 3200x1333 mode.

Is this possible?